# How to fix antd popover arrow not placing correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, antd

[image]

created a popover using the ant design popover component but the arrow is not behaving as it should.
Here are the popover `props`

```
<Popover
      overlayClassName="popoverInner summaryInfotooltip"
      placement={toolTipPosition}
      content={toolTipTitle}
    >
      <QuestionCircleOutlined
        className={styles.questionIcon}
        style={{ marginLeft: '3px' }}
      />
    </Popover>
```

here are the styles

```
:global .summaryInfotooltip {
 width: 250px;

 :global {
.ant-popover-inner-content {
  padding: 9px 11px;
}

.ant-popover-arrow-content {
  box-shadow: none;
  }
 }
}
```

I wanted the arrow head to point down to the `?` mark. Tried many things but now I'm clueless
TIA.

Comment: check the css of the arrow. where are the styles coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `placement` argument of the `Popover` component to `"top"`.